# How to make cookies without using greaseproof paper or a baking tin?

Tags: equipment, cookies

I don't have [greaseproof paper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greaseproof_paper) nor a baking tin and I'm baking cookies. What should I do?

Comment: What _do_ you have?

Comment: What's wrong with putting them directly on your oven's tray? What do you want to avoid?

Comment: Most cookies are high in fat, so they don't stick easily, and very forgiving if you watch them closely.  You could bake them on an inverted cake pan, for example, although it might not be ideal.   The parchment is for convenience and easy cleanup, mostly, although it does mitigate the bottom-browning a little.

Answer (score 6):

You should use what you have available as long as it is flat. Thin is good, if you have no cookie sheets you could use any thin-bottomed pans you have (thick bottoms take too long to get up to temperature, leading to inconsistent results). A layer of tin foil will work in lieu of greaseproof paper in most cases, shiny side towards the cookie.

Comment: +1 for foil.  I've used a double layer of foil in my toaster oven to bake just a few cookies for one after-meal treat and it works like a charm!

Comment: I use aluminum foil for everything, it's awesome, as long as you have something that won't stick.

Answer (score 4):

For years, I never used anything but a good cookie sheet or jelly roll pan. Most cookies have so much oil in them (whether through butter or oil) that they don't stick to anything. If you have a very thin spatula, it helps move the cookies to and fro while keeping their shape (somewhat).

Now, I use parchment paper and love how much faster it makes moving the cookies about. If I don't have it, however, I'm still going to make some cookies. They'll just be slightly oval instead of round.

Answer (score 0):

Grease computer paper and use it as baking sheets, always works

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Many people here might not understand what a computer paper. It would be great if you could add some pictures.

Answer (score -2):

Grease a baking tray with some butter or lard

Comment: That won't help since the OP doesn't have baking trays...